# Optional Date, Time, Datetime filed for Mysql Database

Tags: php, mysql, date, datetime

I have a php form with text fields, multiple choices and Date, Datetime, Time fields, i want to set the date, datetime and time fields to be optional while submitting the form. How to do so.? The values are inserted only Date, Date time, time field are entered.

Php code

// Fetching variables

```
$checkout_date_input = $_POST['checkout_date_input'];
$checkout_time_input = $_POST['checkout_time_input'];


$arrival_date_time = $_POST['arrival_date_time'];
$arrival_flightno = $_POST['arrival_flightno'];
$departure_date_time = $_POST['departure_date_time'];
$departure_flightno = $_POST['departure_flightno'];
```

//Insert Query of SQL

```
$query = mysql_query("insert into reservationform(booking_checkout_date, booking_checkout_time, booking_arrival_date, booking_arrival_flightno, booking_departure_date,booking_departure_flightno) values ('$checkout_date_input',  '$checkout_time_input',
 $arrival_flightno,'$departure_date_time',$departure_flightno)");
```

Comment: Code open for SQL injection, mysql_* is deprecated and closed in Php7 use prepared statements, u can use isset(). Your optional columns must be ALLOW NULL.

Comment: Do you mean you want to be able to store any format of date or time into one field?

Answer (score 2):

**Solution #1**

The best way is to check if the user has entered something, if they have you can pass the value, if they haven't you make the variable NULL.

```
if(!empty(trim($_POST['checkout_date_input']))){
    $checkout_date_input = $_POST['checkout_date_input'];
} else {
    $checkout_date_input = null;
}
```

**Solution #2**

Another thing that you can do is specify which column names you want to insert into the database.

`INSERT INTO table (column1, column2) VALUES ('value1','value2')`

This query will only insert values into column1 and column2, the other columns will be null.
If you set up a number of if statements, which check whether or not the field has been filled, you can determine which columns to insert values into and which not.

Both solutions are based on the assumption that your database columns allow null values, which will be inserted into the database.

**Safety**

Your code is very vulnerable for attacks to your database. I suggest using PDO and prepared statements to ensure the sanitation of your database queries. [More info can be found here.](http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepared-statements.php)

Comment: One more thing left :)

Comment: @devpro what is that?

Comment: Deprecated extension

Comment: You can `trim` the `$_POST['checkout_date_input']` in the `empty` then you don't need the `$_POST['checkout_date_input'] != " "`.

Comment: @devpro yeah okay, but if he uses PDO, the entire mysql thing will be gone

Comment: And don't know OP using DATETIME data type or not or using VARCHAR.

Comment: Yes it but for future visitor this should be good knowledge. I think :)

Comment: @chris85 true, it was just an example for any other constraints he might like to add, idk. Updated anyway, thanks

Comment: @yarwest i tried but its not working. In phpmyadmin i made them to Null - Yes, Default - None too.

Comment: if($_POST['checkout_date_input'] != " "){
    $checkout_date_input = $_POST['checkout_date_input'];
} else {
    $checkout_date_input = null;
}

Comment: @mahadevs I updated my answer (solution #2), I hope that works for you